# MongoDB aggregation returns an empty result

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm trying to count the occurrences of every value of a field of every document of a mongoDB collection.For this task I use the Java Spring Framework.
In order to do so I create a function in a service class that gets as arguments the name of collection and the field I want to count it's values, the function returns a Map where the key is an Object type and the value is a Long type. The problem is when I try to print the Map into the console I get an empty map. If you have any ideea how I can solve this problem I would appreciete.

Here is the source code of the function:

```
public class ComicService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    public Map<Object, Long> countFieldValuesOccurrences(String collectionName, String fieldName) {

        GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group(fieldName).count().as("count");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation);
        AggregationResults<FieldValueCount> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, FieldValueCount.class);

        List<FieldValueCount> fieldValueCounts = result.getMappedResults();

        Map<Object, Long> fieldValueOccurrences = new HashMap<>();
        for (FieldValueCount fieldValueCount : fieldValueCounts) {
            fieldValueOccurrences.put(fieldValueCount.getFieldValue(), fieldValueCount.getCount());
        }
        System.out.println(fieldValueCounts);
        return fieldValueOccurrences;
    }

}
```

The source code of the FieldValueCount class:

```
public class FieldValueCount {
    private Object fieldValue;
    private long count;

    public Object getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I tried to complete the task using agregate.
The result I expect should look like this:

```
{
  Available : 1,
  Out of stoc :3,
}
```

instead I got this:

```
{}
```