# MongoDb aggregation not returning result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I'm trying to find data from a document which has the fields : eventId, title and description and the result has to contain the eventId and a text matching either in title or description.

The query I'm trying to run is:

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "eventId": "12345"
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "title": { "$regex": ".*text_here*.", "$options": "i" }
        },
        {
          "description": { "$regex": ".*text_here*.", "$options": "i" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've written equivalent code in spring boot using the mongo template's aggregate. My code that searches the data:

```java
 public Page<?> searchFilter(String eventId, Class domainType, PageRequest pageRequest, String... text) {
        String textPattern = ".*" + text[0] + ".*";

        Criteria selectCriteria = Criteria.where("eventId").is(eventId);

        List<Criteria> orCriteria = new ArrayList<>();
        orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("title").regex(String.join("|", textPattern), "i"));
        orCriteria.add(Criteria.where("description").regex(String.join("|", textPattern), "i"));
        
        String data = "data";
        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group().addToSet(Aggregation.ROOT)
                .as(data).count().as("count");
        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project()
                .andInclude("count")
                .and(ArrayOperators.Slice.sliceArrayOf(data).offset((int) pageRequest.getOffset()).itemCount(pageRequest.getPageSize()))
                .as(data);
        
        Criteria searchCriteria = new Criteria().andOperator(selectCriteria, new Criteria().orOperator(orCriteria));
        
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(searchCriteria);

        Aggregation aggregation  = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, group, project);

        var results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, domainType, PaginationWrapper.class)
                .getUniqueMappedResult();


        if (results == null) return new PageImpl<>(Collections.emptyList());
        List<LinkedHashMap> reponseData = results.getData();
        var domainList = reponseData.stream()
                .map(hm -> {
                    if (hm.get("_id") != null) {
                        hm.put("id", hm.get("_id"));
                    }
                    if(hm.get("attributes") != null) {
                        hm.put("Attributes", hm.get("attributes"));
                    }
                    return hm;
                })
                .map(a -> objectMapper.convertValue(a, domainType))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new PageImpl<>(domainList, pageRequest, results.getCount());
    }
```

When search request is made for an eventId and specific text, if the text exists in title it returns the result. But if the text exists in description then it returns empty result.

For example: if search is made for eventId 12345 and text "pandemic", it should return result with 2 data.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "eventId": "12345",
            "title": "Spotlight Keynote: Oslo University Hospital and KPMG",
            "description": "<p>The pandemic has forever changed all aspects of the healthcare ecos"
        },
        {
            "eventId": "12345",
            "title": "NBA Properties revolutionizes workplace experiences",
            "description": "The NBA emerged from the pandemic with new learnings and use cases for."
        }
    ],
    "errors": [],
    "timestamp": 1690388775373,
    "page": 0,
    "size": 2,
    "totalPage": 0
}
```

But the current code is returning empty result on search.

```json
{
    "data": [],
    "errors": [],
    "timestamp": 1690389617769,
    "page": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "totalPage": 0
}
```

For same data set if search is made for text NBA, it returns the result. What is wrong in the above java code ?

Went through similar question : [MongoDB aggregation returns an empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671712/mongodb-aggregation-returns-an-empty-result) but didn't find solution.

Comment: Can you use mongo compass to first execute raw query? what are the input documents?

Comment: @silentsudo Yes i executed the query in mongo compass and it returns the data

Comment: can you share sample inmput documents?

Comment: Sure, 
[{
  "_id": "1684172039694001NAhc",
  "eventId": "12345",
  "description": "<p>The pandemic has forever changed all aspects of the healthcare ecosystem. </p>",
  "title": "Spotlight Keynote: Oslo University Hospital and KPMG say YES to advancing care delivery while reducing inefficiencies"
},
{
  "_id": "1686082012480001ny5O",
  "eventId": "12345",
  "description": "The NBA emerged from the pandemic with new learnings and use cases.",
  "title": "NBA Properties revolutionizes workplace experiences"
}]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code, i think you are not using aggregation instead simple find query using [filter](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) wrapped inside and and or

```java
Bson eventBson = Filters.eq("eventId", "12345");
        Bson titleSearchBson = Filters.regex("title", ".*learning.*", "i");
        Bson descriptionSearchBson = Filters.regex("description", ".*learning.*", "i");

        Bson titleOrDescriptionSearchBson = Filters.or(titleSearchBson, descriptionSearchBson);
        Bson mongoQuery = Filters.and(eventBson, titleOrDescriptionSearchBson);
        System.out.println(mongoQuery.toBsonDocument().toJson());

        MongoCollection<Document> news = mongoTemplate.getCollection("news");

        Iterable<Document> documents = news.find(mongoQuery);
        List<Document> result = StreamSupport.stream(documents.spliterator(), false).toList();
```